# I want to show DialogFragment in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, kotlin, alarmmanager

I want to show `DialogFragment` 
when button is `clicked` 
but I have error in my code 
the error is in fun " show "

this my code " button on click "

DialogFragment

```
val pop = alarm_first()
val fm = FragmentManager
pop.show( fm , "name")
```

and this my fragment class  for "alarm_first" :

```
class alarm_first : DialogFragment() {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: 
 ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

    var myView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm_first
            , container, false)

    return myView
}}
```

Comment: replace your `fm` variable with `val fm = fragmentManager`

Comment: i am do that = error again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit this part

```
val pop = alarm_first()
val fm = FragmentManager
pop.show(fm, "name")
```

To

```
val pop = alarm_first()
val fm = this@YourActivityName.fragmentManager
pop.show(fm, "name")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

`val fm = supportFragmentManager`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
val fm = FragmentManager
```

with

```
val fm = fragmentManager
```

Comment: I tried same thing but I am getting fragmentManager as null. I want to show DialogFragment from Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

### We can use DialogFragment to show the content which we need to represent in boundary of your Activity which will work like a enhancement to current feature.

I have achieved this by doing following,

```
val fragment = DemoFragment()   
fragment.show(childFragmentManager,"DemoFragment")
```

> childFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager() of java
>
> tag = "Name Of Fragment".